# Any ways to store data in excel before it calculates and compare with data after calculation

Tags: excel, function, version, datastore

Our company is using F9 software to withdraw data from CYMA accounting software and generate a financial report. F9 uses a function as

= GL(Account, Period, Organization, Year, Activity, Class, Topic, Project, Account Attribute, Transaction
Code1,Transaction Code 2, Transaction Code 3, Transaction Code 4,Transaction Code 5)

An example as :

```
=GL(“1000-100-A”,“Month 2”,“ABC”)
```

The GL function is not an excel default function, but since we have F9 plugged in excel, we are able to use GL function in excel.

We want to compare data before and after calculation. Is there any ways can do versions control? Also, we want to know where are the differences come from CYMA.

Thanks a lot. Let me know if you need any more background information.

Comment: Could this be as simple as [Track changes in a shared workbook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/track-changes-in-a-shared-workbook-951bdf89-9ee6-4777-b31e-33ad0f594d18)?

Comment: You can also change the calc mode from automatic to manual, save a snapshot of the data, execute a "calculate now", then save another snapshot.

Comment: To Jeeped: I tried track changes as you suggested. However, it does not track data before and after calculation. For that shared excel sheet, we never change functions, format etc. We just review data. Thus, tracking changes cannot show which data are different from before calculation. Thanks.

Comment: To xidgel: The manual calculate is on. We review many time of the shared spreadsheet. If every time we take a screen shot when we are reviewing, then we will have as many as 50 pictures/versions of spreadsheet saved. We shared the spreadsheet. If one person takes screenshot at different time that another person, then it will cause confusion. Thanks.